# Why is Joomla 1.5 creating different URLs for the same articles on different pages?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to understand the way Joomla (1.5) creates article URLs.

I created a module to display news.  The module displays all the news, with correct URLs on the homepage `mysite/component/content/article/xxxxxxxx`.

I created a module to display the last article on the homepage and a button, `see all news`, linking to a menu item displaying a page with all the articles. The url is: `mysite/news`.

The problem is the URLs to the article are generated incorrectly as `mysite/news/xxxxxxxx` and they give a 404. How can I get the URLs to be the same as on the homepage?

Update: The new URL doesn't give a 404, it points to the same page as the menu, I mean `mysite/news/` is the same as `mysite/news/xxxxxxxx`, it shows the list of all the articles and not the article itself

Comment: on a side note, why are you using Joomla 1.5? You should be using 2.5 or 3.1 as these are the latest versions, are more widely supported, more secure and have more features.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm just adding some new functionality to an existing site. It's on Joomla 1.5 and the owner does not want to migrate to a newer version...

Answer (score 0):

To create proper SEF URLs, two steps are needed:

1. Be sure to have a menu entry for each article in the list. You don't have to display that menu, it just has to exist. The menu entry's `alias` is used to build the SEF URL.
2. When creating links to such an article, be sure to include the parameter `Itemid=n` in the URL, with `n` being the id of the menu item. In article texts, use this structure:

   ```
   index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23&Itemid=125
   ```

   Joomla! will convert that into a SEF URL automatically, and it will still work, when you for some reason turn SEF off.

   If you generate links in a module, the URL is not converted automatically. You have to call `JRoute::_()` for that:

   ```
   echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23&Itemid=125');
   ```